# WPF ListBox not binding to INotifyCollectionChanged or INotifyPropertyChanged Events

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged, inotifycollectionchanged

I have the following test code:

```
private class SomeItem
    {
       public string Title{ get{ return "something"; } }
       public bool Completed { get { return false; } set { } }
    }

    private class SomeCollection : IEnumerable<SomeItem>, INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        private IList<SomeItem> _items = new List<SomeItem>();
        public void Add(SomeItem item)
        {
            _items.Add(item);
            CollectionChanged(this, new 
             NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }

        #region IEnumerable<SomeItem> Members

        public IEnumerator<SomeItem> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyCollectionChanged Members

        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

        #endregion
    }

    private SomeCollection collection = new SomeCollection();

    private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var expander = (Expander) sender;
        var list = expander.DataContext as ITaskList;
        var listBox = (ListBox)expander.Content;
        //list.Tasks.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
        collection.Add(new SomeItem());
        collection.Add(new SomeItem());
        listBox.ItemsSource = collection;
    }
```

and the XAML

```
<ListBox Name="taskListList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource noSelectedStyle}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded">
              <Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                  <TextBox KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" Width="200"/>
                  <Button Name="hide" Click="hide_Click">
                      <TextBlock Text="hide" />
                  </Button>
                </StackPanel>
               </Expander.Header>
                  <ListBox Name="taskList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate=" 
                     {StaticResource taskItem}" />
              </Expander>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

the outer listbox gets populated on load. when the expander gets expanded I then set the `ItemsSource` property of the inner listbox (the reason i do this hear instead of using binding is this operation is quite slow and i only want it to take place if the use chooses to view the items). The inner listbox renders fine, but it doesn't actually subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event on the collection. I have tried this with `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable` and adding `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well as replacing `INotifyCollectionChanged` with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The only way I can actually get this to work is to gut my `SomeCollection` class and inherit from `ObservableCollection<SomeItem>`. My reasoning for trying to role my own `INotifyCollectionChanged` instead of using `ObservableCollection` is because I am wrapping a COM collection in the real code. That collection will notify on add/change/remove and I am trying to convert these to `INotify` events for WPF.

Hope this is clear enough (its late).

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you don't sufficiently implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` behavior, and you don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` at all. It's probably not worth investigating to find the specific reasons, as you are better off just changing `SomeCollection` to inherit from `ObservableCollection<T>` and getting a lot of it done for you. Why reinvent the wheel? You'll still be able to override methods to customize its behavior if you need.

Comment: Have you got more details on the COM collection you are trying to wrap? I think you should be asking how to convert your COM collection an an ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableCollection<T>` also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. As you collection is simply an `IEnumerable<T>` you don't have any properties to create events for, but `ObservableCollection<T>` create `PropertyChanged` events for the `Count` and `Item[]` properties. You could try to make your collection more like `ObservableCollection<T>` by deriving from `IList<T>` and implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I don't know if that will fix your problem, though.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly the collection already exists and has a base class that is not ObserverableCollection<T>. This collection, even though it implements INotifyCollectionChanged, does not force an update of the list box when it is modified. The question is why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why I keep seeing people trying to implement their own collections in WPF. Just use an `ObservableCollection<SomeItem>` and all your CollectionChanged notifications will be taken care of.

```
private ObservableCollection<SomeItem> collection = 
    new ObservableCollection<SomeItem>();
```

If you want something to happen on `SomeItem.PropertyChanged`, make `SomeItem` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

As for why your CollectionChanged isn't being raised, you are **setting** the ItemsSource property, not **binding** it. Setting it means you are making a copy of `collection` and storing it in `ListBox.ItemsSource`. Binding it means you would be telling `ListBox.ItemsSource` to refer to `collection` for it's data.

Comment: well, ObservableCollection doesn't implement sort. So if you want your data in a sorted manner you need to extend some other collection and implement INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: @Adarsha I just extend `ObservableCollection<T>` to include a `Sort` method. I don't create a class that inherits from `ObservableCollection<SomeItem>` for that behavior. You can see an example of the sort code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7285548/302677)

Comment: note that OP did not extend ObservableCollection<SomeItem>, instead he tried to implement INotifyCollectionChanged. Which expects you to implement OnCollectionChanged. Note that ObservableCollection.Move is not available in all versions of .NET e.g. Windows Phone. So to implement Sort, we need to start reinventing the wheel for sorting. Its either use a class implementing IList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged or use ObservableCollection and reinvet Sorting from the scratch.