# WPF CollectionViewSource for DataGrid - SortDescription not applied at all

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use a CollectionViewSource in order to sort items displayed in a WPF DataGrid.
The items themselves are given via the view model through an ObservableCollection.

The Observable Collection itself changes during runtime (e.g. for new items, it is not being .Clear()ed, but an entirely new ObservableCollection is given).

ViewModel:

```
  public class ViewModel
  {
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
      get { return _Items; }
      set { this.SetAndRaiseIfChanged(ref _Items, value); }
    }
  }

  public class Item
  {
     public DateTime Time { get { return ....; } }
  }
```

View:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding Items}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Time" Direction="Descending"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>

    </Grid.Resources>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"/>
  </Grid>
```

Now - this doesn't work. The items are being displayed in the DataGrid, but no sorting is applied at all.

I've had a look at the view and drilled into the DataGrid at runtime; its ItemsSource property was of type ListCollectionView, which did not have any SortDescriptions at all.

Does anyone know where the ListCollectionView coming from, and why are the SortDescriptiosn from my XAML not applied?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `dateTime` type?

Comment: I would like to point you to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284805/how-to-sort-observablecollection).

Comment: Have a look at [CollectionViewSource.IsLiveSorting property from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.islivesorting(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @grek40 sorry, typo; that is the standard DateTime.

Comment: @arcticwhite Thanks - odd this seems to work there as that seems to be exactly what I tried above; minus actually replacing the underlying observablecollection

Comment: . @XAMIMAX Thanks, tried that - but didn't help unfortunately

Comment: What makes you think that the items are not sorted? Prove your point with a repo including some sample data please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @mm8 - Items pushed to the grid had no sort order (not sorted by their Time property), plus the ItemSource's underlying CollectionView at runtime had no SortDescription associated with them. I've reworked my solution in the meantime so that the underlying ObservableCollection stays the same, and I .Clear() it instead of replacing the collection itself. Now it works - so seems the problems were caused by changing underlying collection (references)