# Sorting ObservableCollection<Class> data in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, sorting, listbox

My program has two ListBoxes. They exchange their items each other by `Add` and `Remove` buttons. During the addition and the removal, I'd like to sort the items (by the IDs), using `OrderBy`, but I don't know how to use this query result. How can I use `OrderBy` in my case?

[image]

It seems that `OrderBy` is working, but I just don't know where to put:

```
IEnumerable<GraphViewModel> query_orderBy_ID = RightListBoxItems.OrderBy(value => value.ID);
??? = query_orderBy_ID;
```

... OK, then I took the right-hand side and put it back into the original collection:

```
RightListBoxItems = (ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel>)RightListBoxItems.OrderBy(value => value.ID).ToList();
```

> error CS0030: Cannot convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'

I thought that casting would solve this problem, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

**EDITED:** Added a `query_orderBy_ID` loop in `Add_Button_Click()` and made it simpler, sorry:

```
using Sorting_List_with_OrderBy.ViewModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace Sorting_List_with_OrderBy
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel> LeftListBoxItems { get; set; }
            = new ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel> RightListBoxItems { get; set; }
            = new ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel>();

        ObservableCollection<string> TestItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        IEnumerable<GraphViewModel> query_orderBy_ID;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;

            TestItems.Add("T0");
            TestItems.Add("T1");
            TestItems.Add("T2");

            foreach (var test in TestItems.Select((k, i) => new { kvp = k, index = i }))
            {
                LeftListBoxItems.Add(new GraphViewModel(test.index, test.kvp));
            }
        }

        private void Add_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var graphViewModel in LeftListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<GraphViewModel>().ToList())
            {
                LeftListBoxItems.Remove(graphViewModel);

                // 1st Attempt: I don't know where to put this result to ...
                query_orderBy_ID = RightListBoxItems.OrderBy(value => value.ID);

                // 2nd Attempt: This substitution fails ...
                //RightListBoxItems = (ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel>)RightListBoxItems.OrderBy(value => value.ID).ToList();

                RightListBoxItems.Add(graphViewModel);
            }
            query_orderBy_ID = RightListBoxItems.OrderBy(value => value.ID);
            foreach (GraphViewModel orderBy_ID in query_orderBy_ID)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(orderBy_ID.ID + ": " + orderBy_ID.TestName);
            }
        }

        private void Remove_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var graphViewModel in RightListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<GraphViewModel>().ToList())
            {
                RightListBoxItems.Remove(graphViewModel);
                LeftListBoxItems.Add(graphViewModel);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Sorting_List_with_OrderBy.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sorting_List_with_OrderBy"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Margin="15,158,0,69.8" x:Name="LeftListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="184" Background="AntiqueWhite"
                 SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding LeftListBoxItems}" DisplayMemberPath="TestName"/>

        <Button x:Name="Add_Button" Height="26" Margin="232,196,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"
                 Click="Add_Button_Click" Content="Add &gt;&gt;"/>
        <Button x:Name="Remove_Button" Margin="230,267,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82"
                 Click="Remove_Button_Click" Height="26" Content="&lt;&lt; Remove"/>

        <ListBox Margin="343,158,0,71.8" x:Name="RightListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Background="AntiqueWhite"
                 SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding RightListBoxItems}" DisplayMemberPath="TestName"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel/GraphViewModel.cs

```
namespace Sorting_List_with_OrderBy.ViewModel
{
    public class GraphViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; }
        public string TestName { get; }

        public GraphViewModel(int id, string testName) => (ID, TestName) = (id, testName);
    }
}
```

The main purpose of this question is to sort my ListBoxes, so the ListBox items should be sorted in the right order [`T0`, `T1`, `T2`]. I believe they will be sorted, if the above problem is solved.

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284805/how-to-sort-observablecollection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderBy` will return a `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` which is sorted according to the sort key. The original collection remains in its original state. You therefore need to overwrite the original collection with the sorted result collection:

```
this.LeftListBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<GraphViewModel>(this.LeftListBoxItems.OrderBy(value => value.ID))
```

To have the `ObservableCollection` sort automatically when adding/removing items, you can configure it once (e.g., from the constructor) by adding a `SortDescription` to the `ICollectionView`:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.LeftListBoxItems)
  .SortDescriptions
  .Add(new SortDescription(nameof(GraphViewModel.ID), ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

**Note**
WPF is binding to the `ICollectionView` of a collection rather than to the collection directly. Setting the `SortDescription` on a `ICollectionView` will only sort this `ICollectionView`. This means the UI appears sorted whereas the underlying collection remains unsorted (or sorted by different rules).

Comment: The 2nd one perfectly works! (Adding a `SortDescription` to the `ICollectionView`) Thank you! However, the 1st one cannot be compiled (Overwriting the original collection with the sorted result collection). So, I replaced `<string>` with `<GraphViewModel>` and put the line after `Add(graphViewModel)`, but some items disappear. Sorry if my setting is wrong, but you might want to edit the 1st one. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed the snippet (I somehow expected this to be a `string` collection without thinking much about it. My bad). But what do you mean by _"some items disappear"_? When using the `SortDescription`?

Comment: Sorry, "_disappear_" was wrong, but only one item can be moved to the right side, and then never move to the other side. It happens when _overwriting the original collection with the sorted result collection_.  I put the line in this order: `LeftListBoxItems.Remove` -> `this.LeftListBoxItems = ...` -> `RightListBoxItems.Add` -> `this.RightListBoxItems = ...` You can try it on your side, if you want to. Anyway, your 2nd one works perfectly, so I can move on. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Ok, now I understand. It's only one time because the view is not notified about the new collection. In this scenario not only the content of the `ObservableCollection` is changing (due to sorting) but the complete collection itself (the reference) is being replaced. To solve this, you can implement either `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `MainWindow` or  implement both collections as `DependencyProperty`. Consider to always make public properties on a control a `DependencyProperty`.  This way when assigning a new collection instance to the properties the view will get notified and will update.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, it works with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I will try `DependencyProperty` someday since I'm not familiar with it yet. ;-) Thank you sooo much!